# How to check if BLE advertisement is already enabled (HCI)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, hci, btle

BLE advertising can be enabled using `HCI_LE_Set_Advertising_Enable`[1] command which returns status `0x00` if *HCI_LE_Set_Advertising_Enable command succeeded* or status code `0x01 to 0xFF`[2] if the command failed.

If the advertisement is already enabled (e.g. calling this command for the second time with `Advertising_Enable` parameter set to `0x01`) then this or `HCI_LE_Set_Advertising_Data` commands will return status `0x0C (Command Disallowed)`.

There are (at least) two problems with this:

- > Enabling advertising when it is already enabled can cause the random
  >   address to change. Disabling advertising when it is already disabled
  >   has no effect. [1]
- BlueZ stack contains the following piece of code at the end of most HCI library functions:

  ```c
      if (status) {
          errno = EIO;
          return -1;
      }
  ```

  which causes e.g. `hci_le_set_advertise_enable` function to return generic fail code `-1` and set `errno` to `EIO`, which is indistinguishable from any other BlueZ error, HCI error or an actual IO error (HCI layer uses UART).

How to check if the LE advertisement is already enabled to be able to perform safe/strict error handling? I cannot find any command for *Get Advertising Status* in the BT Core Specs. I cannot rely on something like

```c
if ((rc == -1) && (errno == EIO)) {
    /* Actually OK, advertising is already enabled */
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

References:

- [1] [BT CS](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) 5.2 [Vol 4] Part E, Section 7.8.9
- [2] BT CS 5.2 [Vol 1] Part F, Controller Error Codes

Comment: Always stopping and starting the advertisement causes the same problem - `HCI_LE_Set_Advertising_Enable(false)` also fails the same way if the advertisement is already disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the Bluetooth stack on the host side should know if it has started advertising or not. That's how it should work. If you manually bypass the Bluetooth stack on the host side (which you shouldn't do unless you are debugging or something), sending your own hci command, then you can't know.